# How to retrieve the parent of a sub-collection item in a firebase trigger event

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a firebase realtime database trigger that monitors when a new chat message has been created, I then want to navigate up the record tree to the parent record to retrieve information from the chat session.  I'm having trouble trying to find the right level of reference to identify the parent record.

My database structure looks like this, chatSessions is the top level (I forgot to include in the screenshot), and this shows a chatSession record:

[image]

My trigger is called with the following:

```
exports.chatUpdate = functions.database.ref('/chatSessions/{sessionId}/messages/{messageId}').onCreate((event, context) => {
    event.ref.parent.once("value").then(snapshot => {
        const session = snapshot.val();
    }
}
```

I've tried as above, and session is returned as the list of messages, which makes sense, so I've tried the following, but this doesn't return anything for session:

```
event.ref.parent.parent
```

Essentially I want to get to the chatSession above, to retrieve the Ids of the two users in the session, so I can identify who to send a notification to in my app.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that I've correctly  understood your question, but if you do as follows you will get a `session` object containing the `driverId` and the `userId`

```
exports.chatUpdate = functions.database
  .ref('/chatSessions/{sessionId}/messages/{messageId}')
  .onCreate((event, context) => {

    return event.ref.parent.parent.once('value').then(snapshot => {
      const session = snapshot.val();
      console.log(session);
      return null; 
      //here, instead of returning null, you may return the Promise returned by the notification sending asynchronous task
    });
  });
```

And, if you want, in addition, to get the `sessionId` value, just use `context.params.sessionId`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had tried this, but it didn't work.  As it turned out, I think because of the call being asynchronous, my code was actually failing with errors further along, and the logging was misleading, suggesting this method had failed.  I stripped it all back, and it's working as expected now, so thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! One key point is to return the promises returned by the asynchronous tasks. You may watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/